# Show summary statistics in R Plotly Boxplot

Tags: r, plotly

I'm making visuals for a large dataset so I can understand better. I'm using `plotly` to make boxplots, but the summary statistics aren't showing up when I hover over the plots. Here's what I'm using (straight from Plotly's website https://plot.ly/r/box-plots/#grouped-box-plots):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

p <- plot_ly(ggplot2::diamonds, x = ~cut, y = ~price, color = ~clarity, type = "box") %>%
  layout(boxmode = "group")
```

The cut type and the price show up when you hover with your mouse, but I'd like to see which prices are the Min, Q1, median/mean, Q3, etc.

I do get an error saying "'layout' objects don't have these attributes: 'boxmode'", but I don't think that pertains to my problem. Is it something wrong on my end or do other people also not get the summary statistics upon hover?

Comment: I do get the summary statistics on hover (r-devel, 64-bit Linux, plotly 4.7.1)

Comment: by the way, the warning (not error) is referenced/documented here: https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/994

Comment: Hmm I'm using 4.7.1 as well, but at least I know it's something on my end. And thanks for the other resource I'll look into it.